# Program terminating after FCGX_InitRequest() call

Tags: c++, multithreading, fastcgi, stdthread

I have something like this:

```
...
int fcgiInit = FCGX_Init();
if(fcgiInit != 0)
{
    return 1;
}

int socket = FCGX_OpenSocket(":8000", 100);
if(socket == -1)
{
    return 2;
}

//point A
FCGX_Request* request = new FCGX_Request;
if(FCGX_InitRequest(request, socket, FCGI_FAIL_ACCEPT_ON_INTR) != 0)
{
    return 3;
}
...
//point B
```

It works good, but when I try to run it with code between point A and B in another thread my program is terminated with status -1 after `FCGX_InitRequest()` call.

Whats's wrong and can I make it properly?

PS. I hope that I get answer this year ;)

Answer (score 0):

`FCGX_Init()` simply should be called on begin of every thread. It means:

```
...
int socket = FCGX_OpenSocket(":8000", 100);
...
//point A
int fcgiInit = FCGX_Init();
...
if(FCGX_InitRequest(request, socket, FCGI_FAIL_ACCEPT_ON_INTR) != 0)
...
//point B
```